# Access to elements of string that contains html elements

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a string that contains html elements such as the following

```
var elements = "<div class='instance' id=''><h1></h1></div>";
```

how can work with it in order to  be able to make like this

```
$('instance').prop('id',5);
$('instance h1').html('hello all');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load it directly into a new jQuery object:

```
$(elements).find("h1").html("Hello All").appendTo("body");
```

Also, `5` is not a valid `id` - please don't use numbers at the beginning of an `id` value.

Comment: It works thank you, but what does the selector "h1", html means?

Comment: We're `find()`ing the `H1` element, and setting its `html()` content to "Hello All".

Comment: mm I usually use numbers in ids, I think it is more unique, doesn't it?

Comment: @PalAla It's *illegal*, technically. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: nop numbers aren't valid string for ids, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html